# PHP - working time minus the time of absence

Tags: php, datetime, time

I know there are some examples of how to calculate working time in hours/minutes in other questions. But that does not solve my problem or lets say, I'm not sure if this is the best way to code what i need.

**Problem:** I got some working times and times of absence, i already know how to check for overlap and i can calculate it, like in example (1):

```
$tmz = new DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

#######################################################

$die_von = new DateTime("2022-04-02 10:00:00", $tmz); # work from 
$die_bis = new DateTime("2022-04-02 20:00:00", $tmz); # work to

$abw_von = new DateTime("2022-04-02 15:00:00", $tmz); # absence from
$abw_bis = new DateTime("2022-04-02 17:00:00", $tmz); # absence to

#######################################################

$ovl = max(0, min($die_bis->getTimestamp(), $abw_bis->getTimestamp()) - max($die_von->getTimestamp(), $abw_von->getTimestamp()));

#######################################################

echo "<hr>ovl = $ovl | ".($ovl / 3600.0)."<hr>";
```

I have to calculate other things, such as surcharges (bonus payments), but these depend on what times and days the employee actually worked. That's why I can't simply subtract the absence from the working time here, I have to know exactly which hours the employee actually worked, his bonuses depend on this. When multiple absences affect a duty, things get even more complicated.

Currently I have prepared 2 arrays (they also hold an array per date), both contain the same date as an index (D1-5), in one I store all working times, broken down by day, in the other the absences of this day. Just pseudo-code to explain the structure:

```
##############################      ##############################
# work array()               #      # absence array()            #
##############################      ##############################
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
# D1 | array();              #      # D1 | array();              # -> Result: array();
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
##############################      ##############################
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
# D2 | array[0] = (10, 20);  #      # D2 | array(18, 20);        # -> Result: array(10, 18);
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
##############################      ##############################
#    | array[0] = (10, 12);  #      #    |                       # -> Result: array(10, 12);
# D3 | array[1] = (14, 16);  #      # D3 | array(13, 18);        # -> Result: array(0 ,  0); <<< what to return?
#    | array[2] = (17, 20);  #      #    |                       # -> Result: array(18, 20);
##############################      ##############################
#    | array[0] = (10, 12);  #      #    |                       # -> Result: array(0 ,  0); <<< what to return?
# D4 | array[1] = (17, 20);  #      # D4 | array(8, 21);         # -> Result: array(0 ,  0); <<< what to return?
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
##############################      ##############################
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
# D5 | array[0] = (10, 20);  #      # D5 | array();              # -> Result: array(10, 20);
#    |                       #      #    |                       #
##############################      ##############################
```

There may be more than 1 shift and/or more than 1 absence on a day. I need the pure working time, so to speak, minus all absences that affect this time-frame.

Does it make sense here to write a function that subtracts the absence from each entry? Imagine the blue box is the working time, the others are absences. As far as i understand, i have to check all possible cases:

[image: Text]

And this way i create "new" time-frames (see example of "Enclosing" which creates 2 new time-frames because of the absence in the middle) of working times that have to be checked against all absences, that sounds like i need some recursion to do that? Sorry it is confusing me a lot, since days...

I saw people solving stuff like this by splitting that (for example in minutes) and loop over the working time period, comparing the position against the stuff they need to include/exclude, counting the minutes and do the calculations, that seems to be the obvious way?

Are there other solutions that I might not see right now?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT-ADD: The data is then required and displayed for billing, which is why it would be inconvenient to create new time windows - which do not match the original entries.

Comment: *I have to calculate other things, such as surcharges (bonus payments), but these depend on what times and days the employee actually worked. That's why I can't simply subtract the absence from the working time here, I have to know exactly which hours the employee actually worked, his bonuses depend on this* Give us an example of the logical output of the desired results. Otherwise we are forced to guess at what you actually need based on abstract data. My immediate direction is to iterate over the DatePeriod to perform the desired logic operations but need something to compare it to.

Comment: And now we have all 3 ways together, recreate/subtract/iterate: Thanks everyone for taking the time to follow my thoughts. You are all thinking in exactly the right direction. For example, I have to calculate and report night (22-06) and Sundays/holiday surcharges, so I have to know exactly when the absence was and when the employee worked. I can't give you an exact example of the output right now, the way I go decides the output. But I can roughly say. For each entry it must be clear how many hours were worked and how many of them are entitled to a surcharge.

Comment: Seems like breaking it down into minutes and iterating over them is the best way to go. With this variant I only have to check whether the current minute is IN an absence or not, if not I can calculate the surcharges (per minute and add them up). I just don't like doing anything in loops unless it's absolutely necessary, it looks like this is necessary?

Comment: Yes, to obtain the itemized reporting to determine base payrate, the times on/off, and their corelating bonuses/penalties between multiple shifts, you would need to iterate over the `DatePeriod($firstDate, DateInterval('P1X'), $lastDate)`, and extrapolate the differences between the timeframes within the date period to apply the desired logic. There's no other realistic way to accomplish this, unless you have static/rigid values within the dataset, eg: can only have 1 shift that consists of 2 on & 2 off timeframes.

Comment: Many thanks to all of you, if you like you can formulate it as an answer, I think we have clarified the question.

Comment: It would be rather difficult to provide an answer that definitively solves the question, as we do not have sufficient example data. It would result in an example of using DatePeriod or simply iterating over the times presented. At best this would be considered an opinionated question, since it was written to be open-ended with abstract theories on how surcharges exist based on scheduled time vs attendance. Which would be interpreted differently by various actors, as can be seen in the current answers.

Comment: Since I worked on something to demonstrate, [this example](https://3v4l.org/TiQ0l) should give you **an idea** on how you can achieve your desired results. Not adding as an answer because I believe it to be a bit convoluted and only establishes base functionality in hours, that doesn't account for surcharges or the detection of timeframe slotting.

Comment: Hi Will, thank you! Unfortunately, I'm almost done and I'm sure you'll understand that I prefer to use my programming then, it's tailored exactly to my requirements and still contains a lot that's still missing here. I'm almost done.

But your code is so well written and structured, I wouldn't hide it from the world. Feel free to send it as an answer, I'd like to mark it as an answer, it basically contains exactly what I asked. I think many people will still benefit from this, even if they are only inspired by it. Greetings to you ;)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you can find out what hourly wage corresponds to someone's working hours:

worked from 14:00 to 16:00.

14:00-15:00 -> 10$

15:00-16:00 -> 20$

then add that up to $30

and then subtract the time of absence:

absent from 14:45 to 15:00.

get the minutes (45), subtract the number of minutes (45) from 60 (15).
divide the answer by 60 = 0.25;

get the hourly rate of 14:00 -> 10$.

multiply the answer by the hourly rate: 0.25 x 10$ = 2.5$.

subtract that from the previously calculated amount:
30$ - 2.5$ = 27.5$

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This way makes more sense from an accounting point of view, as like an invoice when a credit note is created, I would have the original data here, which will then be corrected. But I also have to check all 13 versions of the overlap (see image) if I did this?

Answer (score 0):

The whole business logic is questionable ... because:

```
new DateTime("2022-04-02 10:00:00", $tmz); # work from 
new DateTime("2022-04-02 20:00:00", $tmz); # work to

new DateTime("2022-04-02 15:00:00", $tmz); # absence from
new DateTime("2022-04-02 17:00:00", $tmz); # absence to
```

Is in reality (where the time absent doesn't matter anyway):

```
// timespan one
new DateTime("2022-04-02 10:00:00", $tmz); # work from
new DateTime("2022-04-02 15:00:00", $tmz); # absence from

// timespan two
new DateTime("2022-04-02 17:00:00", $tmz); # absence to
new DateTime("2022-04-02 20:00:00", $tmz); # work to
```

Calculate the offset and add up - otherwise one would have to substract the 2 hours break.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The way you describe would be shown in the picture with "enclosing". When I go this route, I see 2 problems:

1.) I create completely new time windows, then the bill shows services that do not match the services originally entered?

2. If I understand you correctly, would I have to check all 13 versions of the overlap (see image) if I did this?

Comment: A better example: The worker is supposed to work from 2pm to 8pm, but he arrives 1 hour later. Absence would be from 2-3 p.m. If I now simply "rewrite the working hours" I don't know how to present this in an understandable way, the statement then shows the original shift, the absence and the corrected shift (3-8 p.m.)? With all the versions of Overlap, this gives me a headache. Am I wrong in thinking?